# CLLocationDegrees initialization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location

How do you make a CLLocationDegrees? It's not a float, so what is it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [`CLLocation` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html), `CLLocationDegrees` is simply a double. So to create one, you could do something as simple as this:

```
CLLocationDegrees degrees = 45;
```

Answer (score 9):

CLLocationDegrees are typedefed doubles: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126-CH3-SW19

ex: `CLLocationDegrees myDegrees = 2.313224;`