# Expected ) before CLLocationDegress

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Am I missing something? Why would I get this error? "Expected ) before CLLocationDegress."

```
   + (NSMutableArray *)findNextTwentyFiveRemote:(CLLocationDegrees *)latitude withLong:    (CLLocationDegrees *)longitude withLastIncrementNum:(int *)lastPostIdAsString;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLLocationDegrees is not a pointer type.   It is pretty much a just a double.  In other words, remove the asterisk.

[CLLocationDegrees initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497137/cllocationdegrees-problem)

Comment: While it may or may not be correct for this particular function to take parameters typed `CLLocationDegrees *`, it would not give the error reported any more than declaring a function to take a `double *` would.

Comment: Ok took those * out and still the same error so instead of (CLLocation *) I have (CLLocation).

Comment: took out CLLocationDegrees altogther and looks like it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` in your source file?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error for a lot of reasons. It may be due to something earlier in your code, like a missing semicolon. We'll need to see some more code above what you've already shown to determine what it is.