# Cast as double?

Tags: objective-c, double, cllocation

How can I turn or maybe cast something to a double? CLLocationDegrees is really a double so how do I cast it as double so my if always returns doubles and I can change my findAllLocalCountTotal params to double instead of CLLocationDegrees?

```
if(self.lastKnownLocation == nil ){
    double lat = [CLController sharedInstance].latitude;
    double lng = [CLController sharedInstance].longitude;

}else{
    CLLocationDegrees lat = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees lng = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude;
}

NSNumber *tempInt = self.lastPostsGrabbedCounter;



//Make call to get data with lat lng
self.webServiceAllCount = [Post findAllLocalCountTotal:(CLLocationDegrees)lat withLong:(CLLocationDegrees)lng];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a cast and also move the variable declaration outside of the `if` - the `if` & `else` branches are *distinct* scopes and introduced their own variables:

```
double lat, lng;
if(self.lastKnownLocation == nil)
{
   lat = [CLController sharedInstance].latitude;
   lng = [CLController sharedInstance].longitude;
}
else
{
   lat = (double)self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude;
   lng = (double)self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This topic can help you  ? [cllocationdegrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497137/cllocationdegrees-problem)